# Diferences between $V^3$, $E^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

I am studying linear algebra ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JcQJFNVjaA&list=PLIEzh1OveCVczEZAjhVIVd7Qs-X8ILgnI&index=1&ab_channel=EscolaPolit%C3%A9cnicadaUSP)) and at a certain point it is stated that $V^3$, $E^3$ (the space of the points) and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are diferents, but $E^3$ was never explicitly defined and I couldn't find anything about it on the internet. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think $E^3$ here can be *any* 3d (affine) space (of 'points') or specifically the 'physical space' that you normally visualize. **After** fixing a point for origin, a unit length and 3 orthogonal base directions, we can identify it with $\Bbb R^3$ by coordinatizing the points.

Comment: [Wikipedia on the affine structure of Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Affine_structure) may help.

Comment: Look around you and try to answer whether you live in $E^3$ or $R^3$.  In the later case you will be able to also answer exactly where is the origin (the zero vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about vector spaces, we use dimension and base terms to say something about structure of the space, later we may define a transformation on that space. However, if we talk about affine spaces, we do not care the structure. $E^3$ means just the set of all points in 3 dimensional space, this is an affine space. Here we do not say more.